# React Native multiple panresponders

Tags: ios, react-native

With this code how would I add a second or multiple panresponders that can be moved independently of each other? If I use the same panresponder instance and code they move together as one. I want to know how to have several independently draggable panresponders.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  PanResponder,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  processColor,
} = React;

var CIRCLE_SIZE = 80;
var CIRCLE_COLOR = 'blue';
var CIRCLE_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 'green';

var PanResponderExample = React.createClass({

  statics: {
    title: 'PanResponder Sample',
    description: 'Shows the use of PanResponder to provide basic gesture handling.',
  },

  _panResponder: {},
  _previousLeft: 0,
  _previousTop: 0,
  _circleStyles: {},
  circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void }),

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: this._handleStartShouldSetPanResponder,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder,
      onPanResponderGrant: this._handlePanResponderGrant,
      onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove,
      onPanResponderRelease: this._handlePanResponderEnd,
      onPanResponderTerminate: this._handlePanResponderEnd,
    });
    this._previousLeft = 20;
    this._previousTop = 84;
    this._circleStyles = {
      style: {
        left: this._previousLeft,
        top: this._previousTop
      }
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this._updatePosition();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}>
        <View
          ref={(circle) => {
            this.circle = circle;
          }}
          style={styles.circle}
          {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        />
      </View>
    );
  },

  _highlight: function() {
    const circle = this.circle;
    circle && circle.setNativeProps({
      style: {
        backgroundColor: processColor(CIRCLE_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
      }
    });
  },

  _unHighlight: function() {
    const circle = this.circle;
    circle && circle.setNativeProps({
      style: {
        backgroundColor: processColor(CIRCLE_COLOR)
      }
    });
  },

  _updatePosition: function() {
    this.circle && this.circle.setNativeProps(this._circleStyles);
  },

  _handleStartShouldSetPanResponder: function(e: Object, gestureState: Object): boolean {
    // Should we become active when the user presses down on the circle?
    return true;
  },

  _handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder: function(e: Object, gestureState: Object): boolean {
    // Should we become active when the user moves a touch over the circle?
    return true;
  },

  _handlePanResponderGrant: function(e: Object, gestureState: Object) {
    this._highlight();
  },
  _handlePanResponderMove: function(e: Object, gestureState: Object) {
    this._circleStyles.style.left = this._previousLeft + gestureState.dx;
    this._circleStyles.style.top = this._previousTop + gestureState.dy;
    this._updatePosition();
  },
  _handlePanResponderEnd: function(e: Object, gestureState: Object) {
    this._unHighlight();
    this._previousLeft += gestureState.dx;
    this._previousTop += gestureState.dy;
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    width: CIRCLE_SIZE,
    height: CIRCLE_SIZE,
    borderRadius: CIRCLE_SIZE / 2,
    backgroundColor: CIRCLE_COLOR,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 64,
  },
});

module.exports = PanResponderExample;
```

Comment: Have you got the answer?? Actually I am in a need of it :(

Comment: @surya-purohit I know it's been a while, but have you got any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of PanResponders, created like so:

```
this._panResponders = yourObjectsArray.map((_, index) => (
    PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        ...
    })
));
```

`yourObjectsArray` is an array that you use for creating as many panResponders as you want, I imagine each object in that array will correspond to a data instance of whatever data structure you use to create the moveable Views.

Then to actually use it in your View:

```
render: function() {
    return yourObjectsArray.map((_, index) => (
        <View
            style={styles.container}>
            <View
                ... some stuff here ...
                {...this._panResponders[index].panHandlers}
            />
        </View>
    )
};
```

Comment: At what point should I worry about a performance downgrade? Let say I have 10 cards on a given View that should all be draggable independent of each other. Would having 10 panResponders affect performance?

Comment: I can only speak from experience. I have between 10-20 pan responders and seems to work well so far. My Views are fairly simple though, I imagine that the more complex they get, the heavier the performance impact